# Slaves on i²c bus aren't detected

Tags: i2c

I'm currently trying to get multiple i²c slaves with the same address working without the use of a multiplexer on a PI Model 3b.

I followed [this instrutable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) for the creation of a second i²c bus:

1. `cd /boot`
2. `sudo nano config.txt`
3. Add the following line of code:`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=3,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24`

Checking with `sudo i2cdetect -l` it appears that a new i²c bus (bus 3) was created. Nevertheless, no slave/sensor is being detected if `sudo i2cdetect -y 3` is executed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -l
i2c-3   i2c         3.i2c                               I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 I2C adapter                 I2C adapter

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1  
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0d -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 -- 

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

The sensors on buses 1 and 3 are identical and the wiring is the same.
If I switch the buses for the two sets of sensors I get the same result that the sensors on bus 1 (previously on 3) get detected and the ones on bus 3 (previously on 1) don't get detected.

---

I know do not know how to fix this problem if it is even fixable as most tutorials/instructions simply say that you need a multiplexer to get around the problem with double use of adresses. 
[image]
Wiring may look a bit messy but there are no shorts and everything works if connected with bus 1.

- Black = Ground
- Orange = 3.3V
- Gray = SDA
- Purple = SCL

---

- The used sensors also don't have jumpers to select an alternative
  address.
- I'm also not able to communicate with the sensors on the bus 3 over a python script

Comment: Some months ago I read many users reported that that instructable does NOT work.  I tried it for Rpi3B+ stretch and found it not working. Some guys claim that it works, but NO ONE including the instructable mentions which OS version is applicable.  I gave up after wasting a couple of hours testing different situations.  Now I am happily using Rpi4B buster which has five I2C buses and I found at least 3 buses can stably used at the same time.  If you are using Rpi4B, I can show you a debugged python program showing how to use 3 I2C buses at the same time.

Comment: The photo shows pins 23/24 are being used.  You should be using GPIO 23/24 (on pins 16/18).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To operate properly an I2C bus requires pull-ups on the SDA and the SCL lines.

For information there are hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 fitted on GPIO 2/3.

You could try enabling the (weak) internal pull-ups as a test, but for reliability you should fit external pulls to 3V3.

To enable the internal pull-ups on GPIO 23/24 with the pigpio [pigs pud](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PUD) command.

```
sudo pigpiod

pigs pud 23 u pud 24 u
```

Looking at the photo more carefully shows pins 23/24 are being used. You should be using GPIO 23/24 (on pins 16/18).

Entries in `/boot/config.txt` always expect (Broadcom) GPIO numbers.

> GPIO numbering uses the hardware pin numbering scheme (aka BCM scheme)
>   and not the physical pin numbers.

Comment: So I just connect the SDA and SCL lines (of bus 3) with 1.8KOhm resistors to the 3.3V line I also use to power the sensors?

Comment: That should work.  Personally I think 1k8 is a bit low and would probably try a 3 or 4k resistor.  But I'm not an electronics person so take that with a pinch of salt.

Comment: I've enabled the internal pullups and now used 3.3k resistors. What did change now is that after the execution of `sudo i2cdetect -y 3` the table shows up instantly compared to slowly writing each entry on its own but the sensors still don't show up. (also checked if a multimeter that sda/scl now is at ~3.3V)

Comment: It is probably time to have some clear photos of the connections.

Comment: Also check 23/24 aren't swapped.  One other quickish test - connect jumpers between GPIO 23 and 18 and between GPIO 24 and 19 - run the command `pigs bscx 0x130305` then do `i2cdetect -y 3`.  A device should appear at 0x13.

Comment: Added a picture to the post and there is no device detect if I connect those GPIO pins.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see nothing wrong with the wiring.  One last test - use different jumper wires for SDA/SCL on 23/24.  Wires do break.  I'll find my Pi3B and try a similar set-up.  That won't be for a few hours though.

Comment: Already tried different wires and the exact same breadboard with all the wires and connections does work fine if I connect it to GPIO pins 3 an 5 using i²c bus 1.
Take your time I'm thankful for any help I can get.

Comment: *"I've enabled the internal pullups and now used 3.3k resistors."* -> Pretty sure joan meant **either/or**, not both.

Comment: @goldilocks I did.  You are using pins 23/24.  You should be using GPIO 23/24 (pins 16/18).

Comment: I just tested on my Pi3B+ and the bus works fine when tested with bscx.

Comment: @joan I confused GPIO numbering with the physical pin numbering. With the wires connected to 16/18 it workes perfectly!

Add that to your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.